# Como verificar se o e-mail já existe em "tempo real"? Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou construindo um formulário de update. Quero que quando o usuário solicite a troca de email, primeiro eu verifique se o email já não está em uso.
No meu formulário html tenho o seguinte campo:

```
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="" class="form-control-label">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="{{Auth::user()->email}}">
</div>
```

Na minha controller utilizo o seguinte código para verificar se o email já existe:

```
public function perfil(Request $request)
{   
    $usuarioEmail = User::where('email', '=', $request->input('email'))->first();
    if ($usuarioEmail) {
        if($usuarioEmail->email != Auth::user()->email) //Se o email já estiver cadastrado no banco, verifico se pertence ao usuário que está solicitando a troca

            //Email já utilizado por outro usuário

    }//Se o email não estiver em uso, troco normalmente
    else{User::where('userId', Auth::user()->userId)->update(['email' => $request->input('email')]);}
}
```

Gostaria de fazer essa verificação em tempo real, sem atualizar a página. Como proceder?

Comment: Sem atualizar a página é sempre JS com ajax

Comment: Isso mesmo que o @Isac falou, somente com Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, amigo. Tudo bem?

Então vamos lá.

**Código JavaScript**

```
<script>
var route = "/verify/email";
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var data = {
    "email": email
};

axios.post(route, data).then(res => {
    console.log("O código funcionou perfeitamente");
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Algo de errado não está certo, verifique novamente seu código");
})

</script>
```

**Route do Laravel**

```
Route::post("/verify/email", PerfilController@perfil);
```

Se o seu controller fizer o que promete basta fazer essa requisição para o Back End e tratar a resposta depois na região dos console.log, ou seja, onde tem o console.log no *.then* você mostraria a resposta ao usuário no front utilizando a manipulação do DOM, onde tem o console.log do *.catch* você mostra uma mensagem de Erro para o cliente.

**Dica!**

A função *perfil* do seu controller executa duas ações, isso fere dois princípios de boas práticas de programação. Descreverei elas abaixo e como você pode resolve-las.

**Principio da responsabilidade única**

Cada função tem uma única responsabilidade, ou seja, você deveria ter uma função que verificasse se o E-mail já está sendo utilizado e outra função que realiza a atualização do E-mail no banco de dados.

**Acessos ao banco de dados devem estar na Model**

Toda e qualquer consulta deve ser realizada pela Model, ou seja, essas duas funções que eu te falei para construir devem ser construidas na Model e serem chamadas no controller. Não é função do controller realizar consultas ou alterações no banco de dados! O controller apenas recebe uma requisição ($request), pode chamar funções que tem a responsabilidade de executar outras ações e por fim retorna uma resposta.

Qualquer dúvida basta entrar em contato.

Abraços.